# append new information in csv files to existing historical qvd

Tags: qlikview

Let's say I have a "master" qvd file named salesHistory.qvd, and I want to append new monthly sales from file salesMarch.csv

How do I do that without replacing existing information, but adding new months?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, QlikView automatically appends table loads to a previously loaded table if the fields are identical. You can use this to your advantage by using a script similar to the following:

```
SalesHistory:
LOAD 
     *
FROM
[salesHistory.qvd] (qvd);

LOAD 
     *
FROM
[salesMarch.csv]
(txt, utf8, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);

STORE SalesHistory INTO [salesHistory.qvd] (qvd);
```

This initially loads the contents of your `salesHistory.qvd` file into a table, and then loads the contents of `salesMarch.csv` and concatenates it into the `SalesHistory` table (which contains the contents of `salesHistory.qvd`.

The final `STORE` step saves this concatenated table into the `salesHistory.qvd` file by overwriting it completely.

In the above example, we use `*` as a field specifier to load *all* fields from the source files. This means that this approach only works if your QVD file contains the same fields (and field names) as your CSV file.

Furthermore, as this script loads the contents of the QVD file each time it is executed, it will start to duplicate data if it is executed more than once per month as there is no determination of which months already exist in the QVD file. If you need to execute it more than once per month (perhaps due to adjustments) then you may wish to consider applying a `WHERE` clause to the load from `salesHistory.qvd` so that only data up to and including the previous month is loaded.

Finally, you may wish to alter the name of your CSV file so that it is always the same (e.g. `salesCurrentMonth.csv`) so that you do not have to change the filename in your script.